# Custom UITabBarController moved to top leaving white area

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a custom `UITabBarController` and using setFrame in the `viewDidLoad` I move the tabBar to the top of the screen. This works fine.

In `Interface Builder` I have pushed down the elements (buttons, labels, etc) in the `XIB` file of the so that there is room for the tabBar at the top. I have made sure to set the Bottom Bar to none (in the simulated metrics of the inspector) and made sure that the `UIView` is 480 in height.

When I test this however the tabBar is at the top as expected, but the view is clipped off where the tab bar would normally be. Even the background `UIImage` does not show through. It is just white. How can I increase the frame size of the viewController?
I tried changing adding a `setFrame` command to `[self view]` in the `viewDidLoad` of the `subview`, but that did not do the trick.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

UITabBarController automatically sets the frame for active view controllers.

You can try to modify the view's frame afterwards or try setting `clipSubviews = NO` for all views.

Maybe you want to try to execute the following in `viewDidAppear:` or some other place (try!). This will hopefully change back the frame of the view after the tab bar controller modified it.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
});
```